# calculate direction of 3d triangle in stl file

Tags: 3d, rotation

I have this triangle:

[image]

[image]

In this stl file:

```
solid
  facet normal -3.42 2.42 2.72
    outer loop
      vertex 0.75 0.06 0.15
      vertex 3.86 0.06 4.06
      vertex 1.75 0.93 0.63
    endloop
  endfacet
endsolid
```

And I need to figure out a way to get the triangle face direction/angle based on its centroid vertex (orange vector). I do have the values of the centroid but I can't think of a way to get the value of the direction of the triangle. Whenever the triangle is rotated its face/direction should return x,y,z value representing that movement. Any help or hints would be much appreciated. Solution can be written in any language or even pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you already have direction as `facet normal` in your stl file.

In case you have only triangle vertices - you can find normal as [vector product](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-cross-product.html) of two edge vectors.

```
Q = Vertex[1] - Vertex[0]   //per-element differences, like Q.x = V[1].x - V[0].x
R = Vertex[2] - Vertex[1]

N = Q x R  (N.x = (Q.y * R.z - Q.z * R.y) and so on)
```

To find displacements of vertices while moving goes in normal directon, you need to normalize it (make unit length) - divide all components by normal length.

```
uN = N / Length(N)
Disp = uN * Distance (for example, dx = uN.x * Distance)
```

Note that components of unit normal vector are so-called "direction cosines" and they correspond to cosine of angle between normal and bazis vectors. So to get angle between normal and some axis, just use arccosine function (acos, arrcos, math.acos etc)

```
Angle(uN/X-axis) = acos(uN.x)
```

Example:

```
facet normal 
   1 2 -2
length L = sqrt(1*1+2*2+2*2)=3
unit normal
  1/3  2/3  -2/3
angle with OX axis = acos(1/3) ~ 70.5 degrees
angle with OY axis = acos(2/3) ~ 48 degrees
angle with OZ axis = acos(-2/3) ~ 132 degrees
```

Comment: believe it or not I was just looking at that before I read your answer :'D I haven't known that the facet normal value actually what I was looking for. Now the question is I'm getting normal value based on the vertices but I'd like to convert that into 0-360 or even +180, -180 degrees do you know any way to do that?

Comment: In 3D you cannot describe direction by a single angle. Perhaps you need angle between direction and some axis, or between direction and some plane, or you really need two angles like longitude/latitude coordinates at the Earth

Comment: yeah 3 angles values represent x,y,z based on the normal value. perhaps create an angle with the centroid of the triangle and calculate it from there?

Comment: I added info for angles between direction and axes

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you add an example? or maybe take the facet normal value as the input, apply your logic and write the output. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly

Comment: perfect! this is what I needed.. I just converted these degrees to +90, -90 to make things easier.

Comment: I have one more question since you're good at this :). Do you know how to get the normal of a polygon that's shaped by multiple triangles in an stl file? I'm trying to get the above calculated angles with that polygon. So far I have 2 different approaches: 1st is to pick 3 random points on the polygon to shape a triangle then calculate the normal from there (which might not have correct angles because it might be non-planar). The 2nd approach is to get the average of summed up angles in all selected triangles that shape the polygon. do you think that will work?

Comment: If polygon is not planar, there is no commonly used normal approach. The second approach might give something good - note that it would be wise to use triangle areas as coefficients to provide larher impact of larger triangles

Comment: so if I'm using the 2nd approach I should somehow write logic to allow the larger triangles to have larger impact on the final summed up result?

Comment: Yes, it looks reasonable. Simple way - vector product gives normal vector with length equal to doubled triangle area. Sum all these normals without normalization, and normalize only the sum vector.

Comment: do you have a code sample or the steps to do that? also are you familiar with Newell's Method to calculate the surface normal of the polygons?

Comment: As far as I see, Newell's approach is similar to described one, but it is optimized (like shoelace formula for polygon area) and does not require dissection into triangles (in your case you already have triangles, in general case one need to make triangulation of polygon).

Comment: Thanks for your help I really appreciate it. However, I've just decided to calculate the average angles of all triangles and it seems accurate so far. I did implement Newell's approach to get the normal but it always returns positive value for the z. so if the object is facing the -z it would still return +z. I couldn't figure out what was the issue so I gave up. I've followed this implementation example (c++): http://www.dillonbhuff.com/?p=284 let me know if you have any input about that.. again thanks

Comment: here's the question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59124545/issue-with-calculating-3d-polygons-face-normal-using-newells-algorithm