# Issue with calculating 3d polygon's face normal using Newell's algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, 3d, geometry, polygon

I'm trying to calculate 3D polygon's normal using Newell's approach. The problem I'm facing is that the value of z is always returned in positive even though the polygon is facing -z. However, when it's facing -z it also flips the values of x and y as well so if actual value of x is -x it'll be +x and same goes for the y. I can't figure out why that is happening. I hope someone can point out what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I wrote so far (using PHP):

```
$verticies =
[
    [57.36, 30.98, 0.0],
    [52.57, 39.04, 2.76],
    [58.00, 38.33, 10.50],
    [59.89, 31.16, 4.77],
    [62.28, 30.75, 8.01],
    [64.70, 26.11, 6.46],
    [64.90, 21.54, 1.21]
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($verticies); $i++) 
{
    //current vertex
    $pi = $verticies[$i];

    //next vertex
    $pj = $verticies[($i+1) % count($verticies)];

    //0 = x, 1 = y, 2 = z
    $nx += ((($pi[2]) + ($pj[2])) * (($pj[1]) - ($pi[1])));
    $ny += ((($pi[0]) + ($pj[0])) * (($pj[2]) - ($pi[2])));
    $nz += ((($pi[1]) + ($pj[1])) * (($pj[0]) - ($pi[0])));
}

echo $nx.', '.$ny.', '.$nz;

//Current Result = -192.665, -145.6139, 115.1547
//Expected Result = -192.665, -145.6139, -115.1547
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: As mentioned by MBo, your code gives the correct result. Where did you get the expected result?

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé - I've inverted the object 180 deg so the normal was facing -z but I'll check MBo's suggestion and see if that fix it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code [gives](https://ideone.com/f0Y3GU) `0, 2, -2` for rectangle

```
[
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1],
];
```

and `0, -2, 2` for rectangle with reversed vertex order, so I think code is right

Comment: The vertices I have are sorted in a counter-clockwise order. You think that might be the issue? now if reverse that the result will be inverted I think (I haven't tested it yet).

Comment: Yes, all components will be inverted.

Comment: Actually the result is inverted only. Now it always gives me negative value...

Comment: can you help me in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242195/rotate-3d-shape-around-its-centeroid-axis

Comment: Not now. Check for Rodrigues' rotation formula