# Rotate 3D shape around its centeroid/axis

Tags: php, 3d, rotation, geometry

I have a 3D shape defined in STL file and **I'd like to rotate it around its axis/center** using Yaw, Pitch and Roll. However, I've already implemented a solution and it doesn't work as expected as **it rotates the 3D shape around the origin axis instead**. Here's what I've done so far (written in PHP):

```
function rotate($vertices, $roll = 0, $pitch = 0, $yaw = 0) 
{
    if(!empty($vertices))
    {
        $cosa = cos($yaw);
        $sina = sin($yaw);

        $cosb = cos($pitch);
        $sinb = sin($pitch);

        $cosc = cos($roll);
        $sinc = sin($roll);

        $Axx = $cosa * $cosb;
        $Axy = $cosa * $sinb * $sinc - $sina * $cosc;
        $Axz = $cosa * $sinb * $cosc + $sina * $sinc;

        $Ayx = $sina * $cosb;
        $Ayy = $sina * $sinb * $sinc + $cosa * $cosc;
        $Ayz = $sina * $sinb * $cosc - $cosa * $sinc;

        $Azx = -$sinb;
        $Azy = $cosb * $sinc;
        $Azz = $cosb * $cosc;

        //loop through all triangles
        foreach($vertices as $i => $vertex) 
        {
            $px = $vertex->x;
            $py = $vertex->y;
            $pz = $vertex->z;

            $points = 
            [
                'x' => ($Axx * $px + $Axy * $py + $Axz * $pz), 
                'y' => ($Ayx * $px + $Ayy * $py + $Ayz * $pz), 
                'z' => ($Azx * $px + $Azy * $py + $Azz * $pz)
            ];

            //update the vertex
            $vertices[$i]->setVertex($vi, $points);
        }
    }

    return $vertices;
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code above rotates about the origin. If your centre of rotation (say, `$c`), isn't the origin, you can move the object before rotating: `$px = $vertex->x - $c->x` and so on. After rotating, move it back: `'x' => ($Axx * $px + $Axy * $py + $Axz * $pz) + $c->x`, ...

Comment: @MOehm - so in other words the rotation must be executed on the origin? and there's no other way to do that?

Comment: What's wrong with that? You can, of course, create a 4×4 transformation matrix that describes both rotation and transformation, but it's essentially the same under the hood.

Comment: @MOehm - nothing is wrong with it. I was just wondering. but that works too. Thanks for your help. please add that comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @MOehm There's a small issue, so when I add the rotation for example for yaw = 1, is that in degrees or radians? because it applies a big rotating of the object

Comment: That's in radians, because it is used directly in the sines and cosines. A rotation of 1 would be about 57°.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above rotates about the origin. If your centre of rotation (say, $c), isn't the origin, you can move the object before rotating:

```
$px = $vertex->x - $c->x;
$py = $vertex->y - $c->y;
$pz = $vertex->z - $c->z;
```

After rotating, move the point back to the centre of rotation:

```
$points = 
[
    'x' => ($Axx * $px + $Axy * $py + $Axz * $pz) + $c->x, 
    'y' => ($Ayx * $px + $Ayy * $py + $Ayz * $pz) + $c->y, 
    'z' => ($Azx * $px + $Azy * $py + $Azz * $pz) + $c->z
];
```

Comment: perfect! thanks for your help. I just converted the radians to degrees and now it's rotating perfectly.